# Html tag inside body tag. Possible javascript issue

Tags: javascript, html

This is the webpage where I am facing this issue,
http://us.accept.kia.eu/us/models/kia-sorento-2014/

Rendered by IIS, the source code is completely fine but the dom rendering shows a html tag being displayed inside body tags. This is creating a lot of loading problems and possibly crashes ipad safari.

I believe some html is making the changes. Can the experts here tell me how to fix this.

Comment: Source code of the web page seems to be fine in chrome.

Comment: Source code is fine but inspect element shows different story

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The HTML tag with XMLNS is the problem. Fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Issue confirmed

(FireFox Inspector)
[image: HTML Error]

Thee error lays in the head of the HTML response.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-us">

<!--[if lt IE 8 ]> <html class="no-js ltie10 ltie9 ltie8 " lang="en" country="us"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="no-js ie8 ltie10 ltie9 " lang="en" country="us"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="no-js ie9 ltie10 " lang="en" country="us"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class="no-js " lang="en" country="us">  <!--<![endif]-->
```

At the last line of the browser selection you can see that there's a "`<!-->`" which closes the starting `<!--[if (gt IE9)|!(IE)>`. Therefore, as you see in the syntaxhighlighted code above, it's seen as a second HTML tag within the page.

The issue is caused by the webdevelopers on KIA's side.
Though I've tested this with success on a iPhone 5C, this could indeed cause issues with some browsers.